# How would I construct this database?

Tags: c#, database

I have coded a battleships game and I am now trying to make it so that before the user can guess the position of the ships they must get a maths question correct. I then want the difficult of the questions being asked to adapt with the ability of the user. I believe that the best way to do this is by creating a table of math questions arranged in columns of difficulty. For example the first question will be a random question from column 5; if the user gets it correct then the next question will be asked from column 6, and if incorrect from column 4. I have never created a database before and I need help on how to do it.

Comment: That's not really how databases work, it would be a better idea to give the question a difficulty score (this can be very complex or a simple as +1 -1) and then each row can be a unique question with the columns `Question_ID`, `Question_Text`, `Question_Answer` and `Question_Difficulty`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a table called Question with the following columns:

- Name - uniquely identifies the question.
- Text - the text of the question that the user will see.
- ExpectedAnswer - the expected answer to the question; as these are math questions I assume you expect the
  user to enter a numeric answer, which you can then compare to the
  expected answer.
- Difficulty - the difficulty of the question.

By making Difficulty a column, you do not need to have multiple columns of questions. This is an example of database "[normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)". It allows you to run a query like this:

```
select Name, Text, ExpectedAnswer from Question where Difficulty = 'Hard'
```

You also need to have some way of not repeating questions. For example, keep a list of questions you have already asked, then you can use the query:

```
select Name, Text, ExpectedAnswer from Question where Difficulty = 'Hard' and Name not in listOfPreviouslyAskedQuestions.
```

You will need to work out how to pass *listOfPreviouslyAskedQuestions* into the database query.

Comment: I will give that a go. Thank you!

Comment: @HarryThorpe If this answer help you, remember to mark it as correct!